# How to choose a basis set for ab-initio evaluations ?

Tags: computational-chemistry, hartree-fock, basis-set

How do I pick a basis set for an ab-initio Hartree-Fock evaluation ? In other words, what are the important characteristics of a basis set so that a proper choice can be made ?

Comment: I wonder why you are using Hartree-Fock at all.  DFT is more accurate at the same computational cost so Hartree-Fock is primarily used only as the starting point for many-body calculations such as coupled-cluster.

Answer (score 11):

This is a pretty big topic, but the basic important qualities of an atom-centered basis set are:

- The number of separate, unlinked functions it uses at the valence level (the so-called *zeta* count), which allow the modeling of that many different electronic environments, practically speaking.
- Additional higher angular momentum so-called *polarisation* functions to allow for more angular complexity.
- Whether it has diffuse functions to model more spacially extensive orbitals - so called *augmented* functions.

Generally, though, for Hartree-Fock:

- Double-zeta for very quick, very rough structural parameters.
- Double-zeta + polarisation for slightly less rough structural information, large systems (100+ atoms), or simple bonding environments like alkanes.
- Triple-zeta for better accuracy and useful energies.
- Augmented functions if you're working with anions.

Going to a better basis set than this for Hartree-Fock probably won't gain you much. In any case, unless you're moving on to a more complex method, you should probably be using density-functional theory (DFT) instead.

For more information on basis sets including how different basis sets are labelled, I recommend chapter 5.2 in Jensen's "Introduction to Computational Chemistry".

Comment: Great answer. I would add [A link from google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=RDIG48UcZfYC&lpg=PP1&dq=jensen%20chemistry&pg=PA192#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some references that might be useful:

- http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cr00074a002
- http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167797785900036
- http://books.google.com/books?id=Gt4pnp-UFhUC&lpg=PA853&vq=helgaker&pg=PA725#v=snippet&q=helgaker&f=false (if you see nothing, click next then prev).  See http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789812832115_0001 to find the analog version in your library.
- http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/courses/chem6485/pdf/basis-sets.pdf